# Sequelize ternary association

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I want to make a ternary association with sequelize js but I do not know how to do it. I have tried two different approaches:

[image: This is the model]

This transformation leads to another table called course.

### Approach 1

Here I am calling the entities of the relation into the resulting table.

**FormationModel.js**

```
    var FormationModel = sequelize.define('formationModel', {
  idFormation: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    field: 'idFormation',
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
  },
  name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    field: 'name',
    allowNull: false
  },

}, {
  freezeTableName: true,
  timestamps: false,
});

FormationModel.sync({
  force: false
}).then(function () {

});

module.exports = FormationModel;
```

**LectiveYearModel.js**

```
var LectiveYearModel = sequelize.define('lectiveYearModel', {
  lectiveYear: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    field: 'lectiveYear',
    primaryKey: true
  }
}, {
  freezeTableName: true,
  timestamps: false,
});

LectiveYearModel.sync({
  force: false
}).then(function () {

});

module.exports = LectiveYearModel;
```

**PeriodModel**

```
var PeriodModel = sequelize.define('periodModel', {
  idPeriod: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    field: 'idPeriod',
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
  },
  name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    field: 'name',
    allowNull: false
  },
}, {
  freezeTableName: true,
  timestamps: false,
});

PeriodModel.sync({
  force: false
}).then(function () {

});

module.exports = PeriodModel;
```

**CourseModel.js**

```
var CourseModel = sequelize.define('courseModel', {
    idPeriod: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        field: 'idPeriod',
        references : {
            model: PeriodModel,
            key: 'idPeriod'
        },
        primaryKey: true
    },
    idFormation: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        field: 'idFormation',
        references : {
            model: FormationModel,
            key: 'idFormation'
        },
        primaryKey: true
    },
    idLectiveYear: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        field: 'idLectiveYear',
        references : {
            model: LectiveYearModel,
            key: 'lectiveYear'
        },
        primaryKey: true
    }

}, {
    freezeTableName: true, // Model tableName will be the same as the model name
    timestamps: false,
});

CourseModel.sync({
    force: false
}).then(function () {

});
module.exports = CourseModel;
```

### Approach 2

Here is almost the same but I am using belongsTo inside the entities.

**Formation.js**

```
var Course = require('./Course');

var Formation = sequelize.define('formation', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    field: 'id',
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
  },
  name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    field: 'name',
    allowNull: false
  },

}, {
  freezeTableName: true,
  timestamps: false,
});

Formation.belongsToMany(Course, {as: 'formationFk', through: 'course', foreignKey: 'idFormation'});

Formation.sync({
  force: false
}).then(function () {

});
module.exports = Formation;
```

**LectiveYear.js**

```
var LectiveYear = sequelize.define('lectiveYear', {
  lectiveYear: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    field: 'lectiveYear',
    primaryKey: true
  }
}, {
  freezeTableName: true,
  timestamps: false,
});
LectiveYear.belongsToMany(Course, {as: 'lectiveyearFk', through: 'course', foreignKey: 'idLectiveYear'});

LectiveYear.sync({
  force: false
}).then(function () {

});
module.exports = LectiveYear;
```

**Period.js**

```
var Period = sequelize.define('period', {
  idPeriod: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    field: 'idPeriod',
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
  },
  name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    field: 'name',
    allowNull: false
  },

}, {
  freezeTableName: true,
  timestamps: false,
});

Period.belongsToMany(Course, {as: 'periodFk', through: 'course', foreignKey: 'idPeriod'});

Period.sync({
  force: false
}).then(function () {

});
module.exports = Period;
```

**Course.js**

```
var Course = sequelize.define('course', {        
    idPeriod: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        field: 'idPeriod',
        primaryKey: true
    },    
    idLectiveYear: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        field: 'idLectiveYear',
        primaryKey: true
    },

    idFormation: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        field: 'idFormation',
        primaryKey: true
    }
}, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    timestamps: false,
});
Course.sync({
    force: false
}).then(function () {

});
module.exports = Course;
```

Comment: Did you finally found a solution to this?

Comment: yes, I started to use spring data jpa and hiberante with java. Long time ago has passed since I asked this question. With java is pretty easy.